# Bypassing XSS escape filter

Tags: security, web, xss

How I can bypass XSS filter if it escape this symbols: `&`, `<`, `>`, `\`, `'`?

Comment: What’s the context the data is inserted into?

Comment: What strings? JavaScript string literals?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not code related - on the other hand I would recommend migrating to Security.se.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on where the injection goes.
Here is an example of XSS without the forbidden characters:

Let's say a page receives a picture file name and displays it, and does not encode the quote character:

```
    https://contoso.com/displaypic?source=111.jpg

    <img src="111.jpg"></img>
```

If you access this URL, you have yourself XSS:

```
    https://contoso.com/displaypic?source=a"+onerror="alert(111)

    <img src="a" onerror="alert(111)"></img>
```